# Cant save integer array in rails active model...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, angularjs, postgresql, activerecord

Rails 4. PSQL 9.3. Hosted on Heroku. I send my array in angularJS.

On my heroku server I check my logs and indeed the params are sent as an array. Also I can confirm it is routing to the proper `update` route. Here is the heroku log:

```
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"profile"=>{"order"=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}, "id"=>"123"}
```

Despite sending the parameter correctly, Rails won't save this array in my activerecord. Why?

The integer array was added through a `db migration`

```
add_column :profiles, :order, :integer, array: true
```

My update route is like so:

```
def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    if @profile.update(profile_params)
        render json: @profile
    else
        render 'failed to update'
    end
end
```

and I define profile_params as:

```
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(...some other variables, :order) 
end
```

All very standard stuff so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

On the front end side using angularJS I have the following:

```
var params = {
  profile:{
    order: [0,1,2,4]
  }
}

$http.put("http://my_server_url/123", params)
.success(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
      console.log(data)
 })
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit: Figured out what is going wrong, still need help**

So after doing some testing I found that when I inspect profile_params it is empty. Why is it empty when an array is being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is answered in this link: http://jaketrent.com/post/permit-array-rails-strong-parameters/

Basically you need to permit arrays differently. It needs to be permitted like such:

`params.require(:model).permit(:other_field_1,:other_field_2,... my_array_field:[])`